# insert entry to xml in elementTree in python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

How can I insert or update a matching entry each time this method is called?

```
def makeXml(path):
    root = Element("modules")
    tree = ElementTree(root)
    childPath = Element(os.path.basename(path).split(".")[0])
    childPath.set("path", path)
    root.append(childPath)
    print etree.tostring(root)
```

when i call the method first time it should create a new entry.

```
makeXml("~/Desktop/filterList.mod")
```

this first one prints`<modules><filterList path="~/Desktop/filterList.mod" /></modules>`

```
makeXml("~/Documens/sorter.mod")
```

but I want when same method execute it should add a new entry like

```
<modules>
<filterList path="~/Desktop/filterList.mod" />
<sorter path="~/Documens/sorter.mod" />
</modules>
```

but its not happening, instead it gets overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the function `makeXML` is not static, so it won't remember any information about any of the other times it was executed. A simple solution would be to wrap this in a class.

**Update:**  I'm not sure how you are defining unique, but I'm guessing it is either by tag name or path.  Either way it is a simple matter of storing all previously seen items and checking against that.

For example:

```
class makeXmlContainer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Element("modules")
        self.alreadyseen = []

    def makeXml(self, path):
        # Uncomment if uniqueness is defined by tag name.
        #tagname = os.path.basename(path).split(".")[0]
        #if tagname in self.alreadyseen:
        #    return
        #self.alreadyseen.append(tagname)

        # Uncomment if uniqueness if defined by path.
        #if path in self.alreadyseen:
        #    return
        #self.alreadyseen.append(path)

        childPath = Element(os.path.basename(path).split(".")[0])
        childPath.set("path", path)
        self.root.append(childPath)
        print etree.tostring(self.root)
```

Demo:

```
>>> foo = makeXmlContainer()
>>> foo.makeXml('foo/bar')
<modules><bar path="foo/bar"/></modules>
>>> foo.makeXml('bing/bang')
<modules><bar path="foo/bar"/><bang path="bing/bang"/></modules>
```

Comment: perfectly fine, except it will add another if the same entry is already there.